# Unexpected QoS Behavior in Isolated GoogleTest: `endpoint_qos.depth` mismatch

Tags: ros-humble, gtest, qos

I have been trying to test some code using an isolated gtest (`ament_add_ros_isolated_gtest`) that checks the QoS profile used to create a publisher with that reported by the `NodeGraphInterface` of a node using the `get_publishers_info_by_topic` function.

Here is an example test that demonstrates the behavior:

```cpp
TEST(QoS, profile_match)
{
  const auto topic_name = "/test";

  const auto node = std::make_shared<rclcpp::Node>("test_node");

  rclcpp::QoS qos{rmw_qos_profile_default.depth};
  auto publisher = node->create_publisher<test_msgs::msg::BasicTypes>(topic_name, qos);

  const auto graph_event = node->get_graph_event();
  node->wait_for_graph_change(graph_event, std::chrono::milliseconds{100});
  ASSERT_TRUE(graph_event->check_and_clear());

  const auto topic_endpoints = node->get_publishers_info_by_topic(topic_name);
  ASSERT_EQ(topic_endpoints.size(), std::size_t{1});

  const auto & endpoint_qos = topic_endpoints.front().qos_profile();

  EXPECT_EQ(static_cast<int>(endpoint_qos.history()), static_cast<int>(qos.history()));
  EXPECT_EQ(endpoint_qos.depth(), qos.depth());
}
```

and the output of the test:

```
[----------] 1 test from QoS
[ RUN      ] QoS.profile_match
.cpp:123: Failure
Expected equality of these values:
  static_cast<int>(endpoint_qos.history())
    Which is: 3
  static_cast<int>(qos.history())
    Which is: 1
.cpp:124: Failure
Expected equality of these values:
  endpoint_qos.depth()
    Which is: 0
  qos.depth()
    Which is: 10
[  FAILED  ] QoS.profile_match (4 ms)
```

The QoS profile reported by the `get_publishers_info_by_topic` has a `HistoryProfile` of `Unknown` or `int` value *3*. I assume this is then why the `depth()` is returning *0*.

Does anybody have an idea why there is this mismatch?

Thanks for the help!